# JavaScript Error: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Vegetarian') when Destructuring Arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a JavaScript project where I'm trying to destructure an array to set properties on an object. However, I encounter a TypeError that I can't seem to resolve. The error occurs when I attempt to destructure the array and assign the values to an object's properties.

Here is the code:

```js
const restaurant = {
  name: 'Classico Italiano',
  location: 'Via Angelo Tavanti 23, Firenze, Italy',
  categories: ['Italian', 'Pizzeria', 'Vegetarian', 'Organic'],
  starterMenu: ['Focaccia', 'Bruschetta', 'Garlic Bread', 'Caprese Salad'],
  mainMenu: ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Risotto'],
}

let [main, , secondary] = restaurant.categories;
console.log(main, secondary)

[main, secondary] = [secondary, main];
console.log(main, secondary)
```

What I tried to solve the problem:

- I've double-checked to ensure that someArray is not undefined at the time of destructuring.
- I've also attempted to provide default values during destructuring, but the error persists.

Comment: You need a semicolon after the first `console.log()` call

Comment: Now would be a good time to start getting in the habit of always terminating statements with semicolons in JavaScript.  The language can be forgiving about omitting them, but how it corrects that isn't always what one might expect.